# How to achieve the effect of wrapping?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

blender file:
https://mega.nz/file/j9YF0Z4J#8rrsE1ln2UHF0ejdSlyxEPZyeifXm7bujUpGXTSHs_k

How should I achieve this effect?

Comment: 1-off, or  more general (procedural) method?

Comment: looks like it can be achieved with beziers or bezier-like math.

Comment: Have you tried a "sculpting" approach ?

Comment: I have used bezier curves but I can't solve it。@B.Pader, implemented with geometry nodes, not manually